# Is there a vendor(or an app) that provides charge and then refund immediately function?

Tags: payment-gateway, payment, payment-processing

I've been researching about online payments and I'm looking for a vendor that provides **charge-then-immediate-refund** functionality. What I would like to achieve is when a customer subscribes to a subscription, the customer will be charged and then refunded immediately just to check if the card of the customer is able to pay for the subscription.

Comment: How are you going to charge a subscription if you can't process a credit card? What payment service do you currently have?

Comment: I just wanna check if the balance of the card is not empty.

Comment: Or is it automatically checked by the bank?

Comment: You missed the point of my question. You say you want to create a subscription for a user but first you want to verify the credit card is valid. If you have the ability to create a subscription for a credit card don't you also have the means to also validate that credit card?

Comment: The subscription has a trial period. The card might be valid but what I want is to check if the card has enough balance. Just to make sure the card can pay after the trial period.

Comment: There's no way to do that. Nobody can offer that kind of a service because balances are always changing. You have no way to predict the future.